# Tcl Object Oriented extension for porting into Python code

Tags: python, oop, tcl

I am building an status bar for Linux. I already made a module for when a different keyboard is plugged:

```
set initialTeck [eval exec cat [glob /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product]]
set initialTeck [string match *Truly* $initialTeck]

set initialKB [exec xkb-switch] 

dict set table samy 0 samy
dict set table samy 1 temy
dict set table temy 0 samy
dict set table temy 1 temy
dict set table gb   0 samy
dict set table gb   1 temy


proc init {} {
    variable initialTeck
    variable initialKB
    set currentTeck [eval exec cat [glob /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product]]
    set currentTeck [string match *Truly* $currentTeck]
    set currentKB [exec xkb-switch]
    if {$initialTeck != $currentTeck} {
        set initialTeck $currentTeck
        nextKB $currentKB $initialTeck 
    }
}

proc nextKB { currentKB teck } {
    variable table
    exec [dict get $table $currentKB $teck]
}
while 1 {
init
after 1000
```

}

Temy is an .xkb layout file I made for a the "Truly Ergonomic Keyboard", samy a custom .xkb layout for a standard GB keyboard. Teck stores the state of the USB port and a `dict` for the hash table.

Obviously there are many more modules for the status bar, I already use namespaces but as the project grows larger, I decided to go for OOP. At the same time I need to translate the project into Python code to share among developers.

Currently tcl have many extensions for OOP; TclOO, Snit, Stooop, Incr-Tcl, Xotcl and many more. So as Incr-Tcl is similar to C++, is there a Tcl extension which is similar to Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the Tcl OO systems are all that similar in flavour to Python; the languages are different and favour different ways of thinking about problems. Part of this is syntactic (most Tcl programmers don't like `_` characters *that* much!) but a much larger part of this is that Tcl OO systems don't work in the same way:

- They don't garbage-collect values because all values have names that can be stored as ordinary strings.
- They don't have the language integration that allows interception of basic operations.

The net result is that Tcl's OO systems all make objects behave like Tcl commands (which allows a great deal of flexibility, of course) and not like Tcl values (which tend to be pretty simple transparent numbers, strings, lists and dictionaries). This makes for a very different flavour of OO to that which you get in Python.

You can pretend at the simplest level I suppose, but as soon as you start doing anything complicated you'll hit the differences. To say more than that though, we need to pick a more concrete example for us to dig into.

Here's some [Python code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes#Creating_a_Class):

```python
class Shape:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.description = "This shape has not been described yet"
        self.author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"

    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y

    def describe(self, text):
        self.description = text

    def authorName(self, text):
        self.author = text

    def scaleSize(self, scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
        self.y = self.y * scale
```

Here's the equivalent class definition in TclOO (my favourite):

```
oo::class create Shape {
    variable _x _y _description _author

    constructor {x y} {
        set _x $x
        set _y $y
        set _description "This shape has not been described yet"
        set _author "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
    }

    method area {} {
        return [expr {$_x * $_y}]
    }

    method perimeter {} {
        return [expr {2 * $_x + 2 * $_y}]
    }

    method describe {text} {
        set _description $text
    }

    method authorName {text} {
        set _author $text
    }

    method scaleSize {scale} {
        set _x [expr {$_x * $scale}]
        set _y [expr {$_y * $scale}]
    }
}
```

Apart from the obvious syntax differences (e.g., Tcl likes braces and puts expressions inside the `expr` command) the main things to notice are that variables *should* be declared in the class definition, and that there's no need to pass a `self` in (it's automatically present as a command, `[self]`).